# Is it possible to render an object as it appears in the Material Preview tab, while keeping the rest of the scene shaded?

Tags: materials, shaders, eevee-render-engine, text-object, world

I have this scene where I want the text to be noticeably metallic (this is the Rendered View):
[image: Rendered View]

The problem is, since the scene is so dark, it makes it very hard to see the text.

Ideally, I would want to be able to render the scene with the text appearing how it does in the Material Preview tab, while the rest of the scene looks as it does in the Rendered View.
[image]

Is this possible?

P.S. I am using Eevee.

Comment: why don't you use compositing? so in one view layer you render the text with more lights (like an HDRI) and in the other the rest with less light.

Comment: Probably this can help too https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/200071/2214

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the exact same HDRI as in *Material* preview you can find it in *Windows C > Program Files > Blender Foundation > Blender 3 > 3 > Datafiles > Studiolights > World*.

Now choose this setup for your *World* material: Mix 2 *Backgound* nodes into a *Shader > Mix Shader*. Plug a *Texture > Environment Texture* (with your HDRI loaded) into one of the 2 *Backgound*. Plug an *Input > Light Path* into the factor of this *Mix Shader*, use its *Glossy Depth* output so that the HDRI will only be seen as reflection:

[image]

Comment: This is a really good answer. I'm guessing that it would affect all the materials with glossiness tho.

Comment: Yes but in his scene it will mainly affect the letters. Another solution would be to render the letters as a separate layer, then mix in the VSE.

Comment: Yeah, since the letters are the only glossy ones, I guess. i was thinking about a fake reflection solution but this one is better, I guess.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try this later and see how it goes :)

Answer (score 3):

Create 2 viewlayer and use compositing like this:

[image]

to keep things simple i often name the collections as the viewlayers so it's easy to seperate them:

[image]

[image]

for simplicity i used film > transparent and alpha over. But of course you can use whatever combining node you want there.

Comment: Thank you!! Hopefully this works